# ember-data custom adapter createRecord model is empty

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a custom adapter according to the docs and I'm facing a problem that the model that is being passed to createRecord is an empty ember-data object (tried it with console.log(model), there are no attributes).

using RESTAdapter with the exact same app works just fine..

```
createRecord: function(store, type, model) {
    if (type == App.Entity) {
        var url = '/api/entities/%@';
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url.fmt(model.get('id')),
        data: {entity: model.get('data')},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',

        success: function(data) {
            store.didCreateRecord(model, data.entity);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like `url` is undefined if your conditional is false.

Comment: Can you show more code? Fiddle will be good.